# vba color index

Tags: excel, vba

Is there anyway to search for a colored cell? It doesn't have to be any specific color. Right what I have is to specify the macro to search for yellow colored cell. But I need to identify ANY colored cell.

```
cellColor = vbYellow

'is there something like
cellColor = vbAnyColor
```

Comment: You could search for any cell that is not white?

Comment: I did not thought of that. I've tried it and it worked. I just modified my condition to `<> to vbwhite`. Thanks!

Comment: Would checking something like `ActiveCell.Interior.Color <> 16777215 ` or `ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142` work for you? Both values are shown for "transparent" cells (i.e. without interior colour), so having `<>` condition should do the trick. Note that `vbwhite` and "transparent" (no colour) are two different things.

Comment: @JustynaMK just for your interest `vbWhite = 16777215` so they are not different. To verify use `Debug.Print vbWhite`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you're absolutely right, many thanks. I thought that `Color` and `ColorIndex` would follow the same pattern. Indeed `Color` is returning the same number for white/transparent field, while `ColorIndex` returns `2` for white and `-4142` for transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Interior.ColorIndex property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex) and check against `xlColorIndexNone`:

```
If Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex <> xlColorIndexNone Then
   'cell is colored
Else
   'cell is not colored
End If
```

Alternatively you can use the [Range.Interior.Color property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color) as @Dean pointed out in the comment:

```
If Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").Interior.Color <> vbWhite Then
   'cell is colored
Else
   'cell is not colored
End If
```

Comment: Can also use [`Range.Interior.Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color)

Comment: @DeanDeVilliers Right thanks, I added an example to my answer.